# How to build Maven dependencies without a parent project in NetBeans

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I'm using NetBeans 7.4 RC1 to create Maven projects.

Let's say I create two Maven projects, named A and B, and a third named X which includes the other two projects as dependencies.

On building X Maven searches the local Maven repository (and the connected company-proxy) for the dependencies and obviously does not find any initially.

If I run the build command of NetBeans on projects A and B, it performs a maven install, which then installs the projects into my local repository. Now, when I build X it will find the dependency and all is well.

Is there a way to configure Maven (or NetBeans) to automatically build the dependencies (and install it to my local repository)? I know there's a solution to do this with POM Projects (Reactor POM) where the modules (in this case A, B and X I suppose) can be added to it, and the POM project specified as a parent in all the modules - this will allow me to select the "Build with Dependencies" option, which will then build all the modules in the POM project. But this is not a good solution if say project A is a utility project, used in many other projects.

Essentially what I'd like to avoid is building all the dependencies for a project every time I want to test my project; especially when I'm working on the project and its dependencies at the same time.

The key is to try and to this in NetBeans itself, and without modules, if it's possible.

I hope I'm missing the point.

Comment: So that's what "Build with dependencies" is for? It only works when there is a parent POM? That would explain why it seems to do nothing in my projects...

Answer (score 0):

With Compile on Save turned on, Netbeans will attempt to link the opened projects together no matter what reactor they belong to. However this will not *build* the projects (eg. doesn't create an updated jar file in local repository), just link the current project's maven build to the target/classes of these projects.

Comment: Yes, thank you.  I noticed that the Compile on Save, the classes or compiled but the artifact is not installed into the repository.  I read that with NetBeans 7.4 there is a fancy (complicated) way of managing this if you have modules, but other than that there's no hope for these scenarios.